# Can we make an abelian group into a ring by defining multiplication only on a generating set?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

Suppose we have an abelian group $(G,+)$ that is generated by some set $A\subseteq G$. Suppose that we are able to define a binary operation $\ast$ on $A$, i.e.
$$\ast:A\times A\to A,\quad (a,b)\mapsto a\ast b,$$
such that $\ast$ is commutative, associative and such that there is an element $1\in A$ with the property that $1\ast a=a$, $\forall a\in A$.

Can we always make $G$ into a ring $(G,+,\ast)$ by just "imposing" the distributivity laws? That is, we just define, for example, $a\ast(b+c):=a\ast b+a\ast c$ for $a,b,c\in A$, and so on. Is this always well-defined? If not, what do we need to check to say it is well-defined? Are there additional properties that $\ast$ has to satisfy?

Comment: I suspect that for that it will be necessary that every element of $G$ can be written *uniquely* as a finite sum of elements of $A$. In other words: $G$ must be free over $A$. That is stronger than being generated by $A$.

Comment: The suspicion drhab's getting at is that if two elements have two different representations, then potentially the imposed distributivity laws might give conflicting answers as to what the product of the two elements should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is: possibly, but you need an additional assumption to ensure that it works.

You've identified an associative binary operation $*$ on the set $A$ with respect to which $A$ is closed and has an identity element. Another way to say this is that $(A,*)$ is a [monoid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid).

Now at the same time, your group $(G,+)$ consists of finite $\mathbb{Z}$-linear combinations of elements from $A$, *i.e.*, every $g \in G$ can be written as a sum $g = \sum_{a \in A}z_a a$ where $z_a \in \mathbb{Z}$ for all $a \in A$. Given a second element $g' = \sum_{a \in A}z_a' a$ of $G$, you want to define the product $g*g'$ in such a way that it's compatible with its definition on $A\times A$. We can do this by defining $g * g'$ as the convolution

$$
g*g' = \left(\sum_{a\in A} z_{a} a\right)\left(\sum_{b\in A} z_{b}'b\right)
    = \sum_{c \in A}\sum_{a*b = c}z_{a}z_{b}' c
$$

(Note that this is equivalent to imposing a distributive law.)

So, yes, there might be a way to extend $*$ to an operation on $G$, but, as you noticed, it isn't clear that $g * g'$ is well-defined. Specifically, the problem is that $G$ isn't necessarily freely generated by $A$ given your assumptions, which is to say that there might not be a unique way to express $g \in G$ as a linear combination of elements of $A$. If $(G,+)$ is a free group on $A$, then $(G,+,*)$ is a ring and, in fact, isomorphic to the [monoid ring](http://unapologetic.wordpress.com/2007/04/12/semigroup-rings/) $\mathbb{Z}[A]$. Otherwise you would need to verify the operation is well-defined by verifying that if $\sum y_a a = \sum z_a a$ and $\sum y_a' a = \sum z_a a'$ then

$$
    \left(\sum y_a a\right)\left(\sum y_a' a\right) = \left(\sum z_a a\right)\left(\sum z_a' a\right).
$$

Once you know that to be true, then $(G,+,*)$ is again a ring.

Comment: Perfect answer. Thank you very much !

Comment: I have no idea why this answer has been downvoted. Can the downvoter explain?

Comment: @SpenserTaxicabReputation: I'm glad you liked my response! I would also be interested to see why user73985 and I were downvoted here (and possibly Nick, not sure). Without a comment by whomever downvoted, I try not to (and can't really) read very far into why it happened. `:)`

Answer (score 3):

If $G = \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, with generators $1$ and $a$ of infinite order and $b$ of order 2, define $\ast$ by $a \ast a = a \ast b = b \ast b = a$, and $1 \ast a = a$, $1 \ast b = b$, $1 \ast 1 = 1$. This is associative and commutative with 1, but:

$a \ast (b + b)  = a \ast b + a \ast b = a + a = 2a \neq 0$

But $b + b = 0$, so we would have to have $a \ast (b + b) = 0$.

If $G$ is freely generated by $A$ it seems like it does work, however.

Comment: Oops. Should be better now, unless my associativity checking has gone wrong...

Answer (score 1):

If, instead of "making $G$ into a ring" as you ask, you're satisfied with "building a ring that contains $G$", you can look into the [group ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_ring) concept. However, instead of giving the ring's addition, $G$ will give the ring's multiplication by writing $G$ multiplicatively and extending linearly.

The upshot is this works for all groups, rather than only groups which are free over the a generating set.